# Statistical modelling

Tags: probability

I am novice in Stats.
I drew 5 numbers from 5 Odd and 4 Even numbers.
After 10,000 runs, what will be statistical model look like; will be sure the ratio for odd to Even will end in ratio 3:2 ?
If the same model is made for 5 numbers consisting 3 Odd and 2 Even and 3 numbers are drawn will it also end in 2:1 ratio?

What model will look like for 1000 or smaller run?
Thanks in advance,
Rodney

Answer (score 2):

A single experiment seems to consist of drawing $5$ numbers *without replacement*, and then repeating the experiment many times.

First we examine the results of a single experiment. There are $\binom{9}{5}$ ways of choosing $5$ numbers, all equally likely. This turns out to be $126$.

Let the random variable $X$ denote the number of odds. We find the probability distribution of $X$. The probability $\Pr(X=5)$ that $X=5$ is the number of ways of getting $5$ odds, which is $1$, divided by $126$. Thus $\Pr(X=5)=1/126$.

Similarly, there are $\binom{5}{4}\binom{4}{1}$ ways of getting $4$ odds and $1$ even, so $\Pr(X=4)=20/126$.

We find in the same way that $\Pr(X=3)=60/126$, $\Pr(X=2)=40/126$, and $\Pr(X=1)=5/126$.

Now calculate the mean of $X$. The usual formula yields that
$$E(X)=5\cdot\frac{1}{126}+4\cdot\frac{20}{126}+3\cdot\frac{60}{126}+2\cdot \frac{40}{126}+1\cdot \frac{5}{126}=\frac{25}{9}.$$
(This could have been obtained in easier ways.) The mean number of evens turns out to be $\frac{20}{9}$.  The ratio is $5:4$, not $3:2$.

Let us repeat the experiment independently $n$ times, where $n$ might be $10000$. Let random variables $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$ represent the number of odds in experiments $1$, $2$, and so on up to $n$.  Let $S$ be the sum of the $X_i$. Then $P=\frac{S}{5n}$ represents the proportion of heads. (We divided by $5n$ because there were $5n$ numbers chosen.)

Since the expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations, $E(S)=\frac{25n}{9}$, and $E(P)=\frac{5}{9}$, which was to be expected.

But of course there is variability, $P$ is a random variable, and it is unlikely that the proportion of heads will be *exactly* $\frac{5}{9}$.

To make further progress, we need the *variance* of $X$. We have here a [*hypergeometric distribution*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) It turns out that the variance of $X$ is 
$\frac{50}{81}$. We omit the slightly unpleasant details of the computation. To get the variance of $S$, multiply by $n$. To get the variance of $P$, divide the variance of $S$ by $25n^2$.  We find that $P$ has variance $\frac{2}{81n}$, so standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt{2/(81n)}$.  For $n=10000$, $\sigma$ is about $0.015713$.

It is very painful to find the exact distribution of $P$. However, the Central Limit Theorem works nicely here, $P$ will have a nearly normal distribution. Because of this, it turns out that a very good approximation to the probability that $P$ is $\le a$ is given by 
$$\Pr(P\le a)\approx \Pr\left(Z \le \frac{a-\frac{5}{9}}{\sigma}\right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. Now the required probability can be calculated, with excellent accuracy, by using standard normal tables, or appropriate software.

You asked about $n=1000$. Again, this is plenty large enough for the normal approximation to be very good.  It is only when the number $n$ gets into the below $50$ range that the normal approximation may not be adequate.

Comment: Hi André,Thanks for nswering it in simple words. It has helped me to understand. I appreciate your time and effort,

Comment: Hi Andre,This work has sprung up again, I am wondering Central Limit Theorem is possible to experiment by using Microsoft Excel 2007? I use Excel extensively but confess not used for statistical modelling, any guidance possible?